# Creating Android Q&A using SQLite or SharedPreferences

Tags: android, random, android-sqlite, android-sharedpreferences

Can you guys help me on where to start creating an android app mentioned above? I'm trying to create an android app where my questions and its answer as well as their corresponding correct answers are stored in an sqlite database. I want them to be retrieved randomly for example everytime the user starts the app the questions are always inserted randomly and everytime the user gives either a correct or wrong answer another random question is place. Would you guys refer me to any tutorial. I only see simple q&a app tutorials but they are not cast randomly. Plus one questions do I need either sqlite or sharedpreferences or both?

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is like a very simple Java Hashmap. Would you use a Hashmap for a Q&A? Probably not; how would you relate the questions to their answers with that?

Therefore, you have relational data. Use a relational database like SQLite.

Comment: i guess I'd be using SharedPreferences for the score then. But as mentioned on the post do you have any idea where I could look for a good tutorial using the sqlite then.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow, sorry. If you find a tutorial on your own and don't understand it, find another. You may also just want an intro to SQL, in general, if you don't understand that.

Comment: Thanks dude I'll take that advice.